# Question on: it holds "trivially".

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am not really interested in the proof per say, but only the red underlined part. I have some idea how to do it but I just want to make sure. It feels like it should be obvious to me by now but still:

**The theorem**

[image]

**My Question**

I am not really sure what they mean that result hold trivially

Here is what I attempted:

let $x = 0$ and $y > 0$

thus $|<x,y>| = |<\textbf{0},y>| = |<0 \cdot \textbf{0},y>| = 0 \cdot|<\textbf{0},y>| = 0$

and as $\sqrt{<x,x>}\cdot \sqrt{<y,y>} = 0\cdot \sqrt{<y,y>} = 0$

thus by equating the two equations above: $|<x,y>| =\sqrt{<x,x>}\cdot \sqrt{<y,y>}$

which implies: $|<x,y>| \leq \sqrt{<x,x>}\cdot \sqrt{<y,y>}$

Comment: That's basically it.

Comment: @RushabhMehta, thank you for your reply

Comment: But $y>0$ makes no sense. $y$ is a vector, not a number.

Comment: Just so you know, the correct TeX for the inner product symbols $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ are `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Here, if $x=0$ or $y=0$ , the left side is obviously $0$ and the right side is always non-negative (square roots are always non-negative) , hence the inequality must hold.

Comment: Of course, the right side is even $0$ in the case $x=0$ or $y=0$ , but we do not need this to approve the inequality for this case.

Comment: If $x=0$ or $y=0$, the inequality just becomes $0\le0$, and if that's not trivial, nothing is. Unfortunately, many authors in mathematics use "trivially" just because they are too lazy to write up a more or less simple explanation.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Question on: it holds "trivially"." says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: Per se, not per say. It's Latin. :)

Answer (score 3):

In this case "the result holds trivially" means that you can check the inequality simply by *inserting $x = 0$ or $y= 0$*.

In fact, if $x=0$ or $y = 0$, then by bilinearity

1. $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ or  $\langle y, y \rangle = 0$
2. $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.

This means that both LHS and RHS are $0$.